# Why the value function getX() and getY() are printinf '0' after creating DDerived class OBJ

Tags: java

In my code there are 3 classes other than main class

1. Base
2. Derived
3. DDerived

Base is inherited by Derived,
Derived is inherited by DDerived

So,
When i called Derived class function(getY) along with Base class function(getX) it simply printed the set values but when i created DDerived class object and called getX() & getY() it printed zero although i set the values as 5 & 10.

package C10_Inheritance;

```
class Base{
    int x;
    Base(){
        System.out.println("I am Base class Constructor.");
    }
    Base(int x){
        System.out.println("I am Base class Overloaded Constructor with value(integer) : " + x);
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void getX() {
        System.out.println("X : "+x);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{

    int y;
    Derived()   {
        super(5);
        System.out.println("I am Derived class Constructor.");
    }
    Derived(int x,int y){
        super(10);
        System.out.println("I am Derived class Overloaded Constructor with value(int,int) : "+x+" "+y);
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void getY() {
        System.out.println("Y : "+y);
    }
    
}

    class DDerived extends Derived{
    DDerived() {
        System.out.println("I am Derived class Constructor from another Derived class");
    }
    DDerived(int x,int y,int z){
        super(x,y);
        System.out.println("I am Derived of Derived class Overloaded Constructor with value(int,int,int) : "+x+" "+y+" "+z);
    }
}

public class P38_Constructor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d = new Derived(5,10);
        d.setX(5);
        d.setY(10);
        d.getX();
        d.getY();
        DDerived dd = new DDerived(1,2,3);
        dd.getX();
        dd.getY();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> "when i created DDerived class object and called getX() & getY() it printed zero although i set the values as 5 & 10".

No, you didn't set the values in `dd` to anything, hence they were displayed as zero.

The constructors don't set the fields `x` and `y`.  If you want them to do this, you will have to add lines `this.x = x` to the `Base` constructor and and `this.y = y` to the `Derived` constructor.

The setter methods `setX` and `setY` do set values for `x` and `y`. You create a `Derived` object, use `setX` and `setY` to set values for `x` and `y`, and then `d.getX()` and `d.getY()` then print them out.  However, when you create `dd` as a new `DDerived` object, you don't call `setX` and `setY` on `dd`, hence `x` and `y` are left at zero.